# ggplot secondary axis scaling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm still pretty much a novice with R and ggplot.  I have the following code

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(dplyr)    
library(tidyr)  

maxDate <- "2020-07-07"

my_dates <- function(d) {
  seq( d[1] + (wday(maxDate) - wday(d[1])+1) %% 7, d[2] + 6, by = "week")
}

stateWeekly <- #structure at https://pastebin.com/jT8WV4dy
endpoints <- stateWeekly %>% 
  group_by(state) %>%
  filter(weekStarting == max(weekStarting)) %>%
  select(weekStarting, posRate, state, cumRate, posRateChange) %>%
  ungroup()

g <- stateWeekly %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(weekStarting))) +
  geom_col(aes(y=100*dailyTest), size=0.75, color="darkblue", fill="white") +
  geom_line(aes(y=cumRate), size = 0.75, color="red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=posRate), size = 0.75, color="forestgreen") +
  geom_point(data = endpoints,size = 1.5,shape = 21,
             aes(y = cumRate), color = "red", fill = "red", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label(data=endpoints, aes(label=paste(round(cumRate,1),"%",sep=""),
                                 x=as.Date("2020-04-07", format="%Y-%m-%d"), y = 80), 
             color="red",
             show.legend = FALSE, 
             nudge_y = 12) +
  geom_label(data=endpoints, aes(label=paste(round(posRateChange,1),"%",sep=""),
                                 x=as.Date("2020-04-28", format="%Y-%m-%d"), y = 80), 
             color="forestgreen",
             show.legend = FALSE, 
             nudge_y = 12) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Cum Test Positivity Rate", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name="Weekly % of Pop Tested")) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = my_dates, date_labels = "%b %d") +
  labs(x = "Week Beginning") +
  #title = "COVID-19 Testing",
  #subtitle = paste("Data as of", format(maxDate, "%A, %B %e, %y")),
  #caption = "HQ AFMC/A9A \n Data: The COVID Tracking Project (https://covidtracking.com)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color='red'),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1),
        strip.background =element_rect(fill="white"),
        strip.text = element_text(colour = 'blue')) +
  #coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,90)) +
  facet_wrap(~ state)


print(g)
```

Which produces this chart

[image]

Georgia has obviously been screwing with their COVID data (again) so nevermind the negative testing :)

What I'd like to do is scale the secondary axis so that the testing rate lines aren't so squished...they're very small numbers but I'd like to be able to see more differentiation.  Any guidance on how to achieve that would be most appreciated.

Edit:
One suggestion below was to change `facet_wrap(~ state)` to `facet_wrap(~ state, scales='free')` Doing so changes the chart only slightly

[image]

I can fix the label anchors, but this really didn't offer the level of differentiation in the line plots I was hoping for.

A second suggestion was the change `sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name="Weekly % of Pop Tested"))` to `sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1000, name="Weekly % of Pop Tested"))`

As far as I can tell, that does nothing to the actual plot and just changes the axis markings:

[image]

Finally, I've been struggling to implement the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales) from Dag Hjermann.  My secondary axis is the Weekly % of Population Tested, which is represented in the geom_col.  A reasonable range for that is 0-1.1.  The primary axis is the line plots, test positivity rates, which vary from 0-30.  So if I follow that solution, I should add

```
ylim.prim <- c(0, 30)   
ylim.sec <- c(0, 1.1)

b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])
```

and then change the plot code to read

```
geom_col(aes(y=a + 100*dailyTest*b), size=0.75, color="darkblue", fill="white")
```

and the secondary axis to

```
sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. -a)/(b*100), name="Weekly % of Pop Tested"))
```

Doing so produces the following

[image]

which is clearly not right.

At the risk of sounding really dumb here, is the issue at least somewhat due to the line plots (what I want to scale) being on the **primary** axis?

Comment: Try adding `facet_wrap(~ state,scales='free')`

Comment: Hi check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales   the second answer provided by Dag Hjermann

Comment: @Duck See edits to OP....that helped a little, but not really what I was trying to achieve

Comment: @user12256545 See edits to OP...struggling to figure out how to implement that solution.  I think I'm just not "getting it" unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use permille instead of percentage.

```
scale_y_continuous(name = "Cum Test Positivity Rate", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1000, name="Weekly ‰ of Pop Tested"))
```